# How to perform full text search in MySQL joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, e-commerce

I'm creating e-commerce web site using `MySQL`. I have successfully created and inserted data to database.

Here is my database schema

```
table: categories                    table: product_types
+----+--------------+            +----+-------------+------------+
| id | name         |            | id | category_id | name       |
+----+--------------+            +----+-------------+------------+
|  1 | Electronics  |            |  1 |           1 | Smartphone |
|  2 | Fashion      |            |  2 |           1 | Speakers   |
+----+--------------+            +----+-------------+------------+

    table: products
+----+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+-------+
| id | product_type_id | category_id | name              | price |
+----+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+-------+
|  1 |               1 |           1 | Samsung Galaxy A3 |   300 |
|  2 |               1 |           1 | Samsung Galaxy A7 |   400 |
+----+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+-------+

    table: options                         table: option_values
+----+-----------------+-------+       +----+-----------+------------+
| id | product_type_id | name  |       | id | option_id | name       |
+----+-----------------+-------+       +----+-----------+------------+
|  1 |               1 | RAM   |       |  1 |         1 | 512 MB     |
|  2 |               1 | Screen|       |  2 |         1 | 1 GB       |
|  3 |               1 | OS    |       |  3 |         3 | Android 5  |
+----+-----------------+-------+       |  4 |         3 | Android 6  |
                                       |  5 |         2 | HD         |
                                       |  6 |         2 | FHD        |
                                       +----+-----------+------------+
     table: product_option_values
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------+
| id | product_id | option_id | option_value_id |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------+
| 15 |          1 |         1 |               1 |
| 16 |          1 |         2 |               5 |
| 17 |          1 |         3 |               3 |
| 18 |          2 |         1 |               2 |
| 19 |          2 |         2 |               6 |
| 20 |          2 |         3 |               4 |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Search must trigger through `name` column of each table and return `name` and `price` from `products` table.
The problem is that I don't know how to perform full text search joining all that tables.

Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: I do not think you need so many joins, To get better response time , I think it is better to avoid some normalization. For instance , option value table can use option name instead of option_id and option value name can be used instead of option_value_id. This way you can avoid join for search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a query that `LEFT JOIN`s on each table to search with a condition based on fulltext search function `MATCH`, with a `WHERE` clause to filter out non-matching records. The `SELECT DISTINCT` ensures that you will not see duplicates.

We need to adjust manually the `JOIN` criteria from each table to `products` : `option_values` is the most complicated case as it does not directly references `products` (an additional join on `product_option_values` is needed, aliased `pov` below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.name, p.price
FROM 
    products p
    LEFT JOIN categories c
        ON  MATCH(c.name) AGAINST('foo' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
        AND c.id = p.category_id
    LEFT JOIN product_types pt
        ON  MATCH(pt.name) AGAINST('foo' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
        AND pt.category_id = p.category_id
    LEFT JOIN options o
        ON  MATCH(o.name) AGAINST('foo' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
        AND o.product_type_id = p.product_type_id  
    LEFT JOIN product_option_values pov 
        ON  pov.product_id = p.id 
    LEFT JOIN option_values ov
        ON  MATCH(ov.name) AGAINST('foo' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
        AND ov.id = pov.option_value_id 
WHERE 
    COALESCE(c.id, pt.id, o.id, ov.id) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, and what about `options` and  `option_values`? How can I join them too?

Comment: @SDeaV : that's what I wrote, you need to adapt for other relationships... Anyway, I updated my answer with the full SQL code.

Comment: Thank you @GMB. But there is one more thing thats actually the hardest for me. And I don't really get it. Last table `product_option_values`  there is relation between `option_values` and `proucts`. For example "512 MB" of RAM and "HD" screen only for `product` with id = 1. How that query will handle it?

Comment: The query handles it by adding an additional join, through table `options`: so the relation is like `option_values (ov) > options (o2) > products (p)`. Read carefully the query.

Comment: it gives this error.  SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND o2.product_type_id = p.product_type_id 
    LEFT JOIN option_values  ov
  ' at line 14

Comment: mysql.exe  Ver 8.0.12 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Comment: @SDeaV that was a typo, I just fixed it

Comment: thanks a lot. But about `option_values` table, it's not what I wanted. Its joining with `product_type_id`. But it should join with `product_id` in `product_option_values` table... Now when I search 'FHD' it return both products instead only product with id = 2...

Comment: Thank you a lot. I just edited some typo. And one more favor. Could you please make it searchable in `products` table. With `name` and `price` columns.